# Can an Azure IPSEC gateway be used with a normal Azure web app?

Tags: azure, ipsec, azure-web-apps

We have a simple php website which needs to connect to a 3rd party API, and that third party requires a point to point IPSEC VPN.

Azure has an ipsec gateway product for this, but how does one use it with a web app?

There are 3 categories of web app: Dev, Production and isolated.

CAn the gateway be used with a "production" instance?  the isolated allows setting up a private network, which will presumably work with the ipsec gateway, but the cost is prohibative

Assuming we have a web app using this IPSEC gateway, is there any way a developer at home can "see" the API Address?  If we were using a linux box, I would simply use ssh tunnels, but I am guessing you cant use ssh tunnels to a web app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Private Endpoints](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview) which are available with Azure App Service Premium v2, and provision the App Service Plan in a VNet that has a VPN established with your API subnet.

[Using Private Endpoints for Azure Web App (Preview)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/private-endpoint)

For testing in a development environment, you could try tunneling with ngrok, see this example for an idea of what will look like:

[Remotely debugging PHP on Azure Web Apps with ngrok](https://hajekj.net/2016/09/06/remotely-debugging-php-on-azure-web-apps-with-ngrok/)

Comment: Private endpoints restrict access to the web app to the vnet, it does not allow access to resources in the vNet. For that you need regional vnet integration - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet